# XElement and it's attributes

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

I've been looking for clarification between XName , XNamespace & XElement.Name.LocalName , from msdn.microsoft.com the example states that

```
  XNamespace ns = "http://www.adventure-works.com";
  XElement root = new XElement(ns + "Root", "content");
  Console.WriteLine(root.Name);
```

Q. Does Xelement has to have a namespace necessarily?

When I use it like:

```
 XElement xEle = XElement.Parse(xml);
 String tagName = xEle.Name.LocalName;
```

It gives the first Element's Name, why?

(Please clarify if possible the difference & possible usage of  XElement.XName & XElement.XName.LocalName)

Comment: Namespaces are optional.  `XName` consists of a namespace and a name.  What don't you understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `XElement` has a name, represented as an [`XName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That `XName` may or may not have a namespace associated with it. If it doesn't, the [`XName.Namespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.namespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property will return [`XNamespace.None`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.none%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

An `XName` is a fully-qualified name, basically - whereas `XName.LocalName` will only give the local part.

So in your example:

- The local name is `Root`
- The namespace URI is `http://www.adventure-works.com`

The `XName` with a namespace is *not* the same as an `XName` without a namespace (or with a different namespace). So for example, the `Element(XName)` method will *not* find an element with a name with the specified local name but a different namespace.

Answer (score 1):

> Q. Does Xelement has to have a namespace necessarily?

No.

> It gives the first Element's Name, why?

Because you are parsing your XML and getting the root element that contains all elements.So it is giving you the `root` element's name.